# Do Na or Li need heat in order to react with Cl₂?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox

I've read how putting a burning piece of sodium in chlorine would produce white $\ce{NaCl}$ fumes. However, I can't find out whether Na or Li can react with $\ce{Cl2}$ *without* heating or burning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From personal experience, Na(*s*) and Cl<sub>2</sub>(*g*) react at room temperature without added energy. Li(*s*) and Cl<sub>2</sub>(*g*) should do so also.

Consider the following heat of formation data harvested from [the NIST Chemistry Webbook](http://webbook.nist.gov):

For [NaCl](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C7647145&Units=SI&Mask=2#Thermo-Condensed):
$$\ce{Na(s) + } \frac 1 2\ce{Cl2(g)->NaCl(s)}\quad \Delta H_f^o=-411.12 \; kJ/mol $$

For [LiCl](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C7447418&Units=SI&Mask=2#Thermo-Condensed):
$$\ce{Li(s) + } \frac 1 2\ce{Cl2(g)->LiCl(s)}\quad \Delta H_f^o=-408.27 \; kJ/mol $$

These data suggest that both reactions should occur without added heat. However, the rate of reaction is not determinable from these data. The reaction between Li(*s*) and Cl<sub>2</sub>(*g*) will likely be slower.

Comment: In general, the NIST Chemistry Webbook is a great resource for physical constants, phase change and thermochemistry data, and spectroscopy (IR, MS, but not NMR).

Comment: Presumably the thickness of the surface hydroxide/carbonate coating that forms in air will affect whether any *particular* metal sample will react at room temperature.

Comment: These data suggest _nothing_. Thermodynamically, Mg or Al should react with oxygen without added heat, yet in fact they would just sit there for ages, not doing anything.